# How to get aggregate data from a dynamic number of related rows in adjacent table

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.4

I have a table of matches played, roughly looking like this:

```
player_id | match_id | result | opponent_rank
----------------------------------------------
82        | 2847     |   w    |   42
82        | 3733     |   w    |  185
82        | 4348     |   l    |   10
82        | 5237     |   w    |  732
82        | 5363     |   w    |   83
82        | 7274     |   w    |    6
51        | 2347     |   w    |   39
51        | 3746     |   w    |  394
51        | 5037     |   l    |   90
...       | ...      |  ...   |  ...
```

To get all the winning streaks (not just top streak by any player), I use this query:

```
SELECT player.tag, s.streak, match.date, s.player_id, s.match_id FROM (
    SELECT streaks.streak, streaks.player_id, streaks.match_id FROM (
        SELECT w1.player_id, max(w1.match_id) AS match_id, count(*) AS streak FROM (
            SELECT w2.player_id, w2.match_id, w2.win, w2.date, sum(w2.grp) OVER w AS grp FROM (
                SELECT m.player_id, m.match_id, m.win, m.date, (m.win = false AND LAG(m.win, 1, true) OVER w = true)::integer AS grp FROM matches_m AS m
                WHERE matches_m.opponent_position<'100'
                    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY m.player_id ORDER BY m.date, m.match_id)
                    ) AS w2
                    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY w2.player_id ORDER BY w2.date, w2.match_id)
                ) AS w1
            WHERE w1.win = true
            GROUP BY w1.player_id, w1.grp
            ORDER BY w1.player_id DESC, count(*) DESC
        ) AS streaks
    ORDER BY streaks.streak DESC
    LIMIT 100
    ) AS s
LEFT JOIN player ON player.id = s.player_id
LEFT JOIN match ON match.id = s.match_id
```

And the result looks like this (note that this is not a fixed table/view, as the query above can be extended by certain parameters such as nationality, date range, ranking of players, etc):

```
player_id | match_id | streak
-------------------------------
82        | 3733     |  2
82        | 7274     |  3
51        | 3746     |  2
...       | ...      |  ...
```

What I want to add now is a bunch of aggregate data to provide details about the winning streaks. For starters, **I'd like to know the average rank of the opponents during each those streaks**. Other data are the duration of the streak in time, first and last date, opponent name who ended the streak or if it's still ongoing, and so on. I've tried various things - CTE, some elaborate joins, unions, or adding them in as lag functions in the existing code. But I'm completely stuck how to solve this.

As is obvious from the code, my SQL skills are very basic, so please excuse any mistakes or inefficient statements. For complete context, I'm using Postgres 9.4 on Debian, the matches_m table is a materialized view with 550k lines (query takes 2.5s right now). The data comes from http://aligulac.com/about/db/, I just mirror it to create the aforementioned view.

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328) already asked here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/215882/how-to-get-aggregate-data-from-a-dynamic-number-of-related-rows-in-adjacent-tabl

Comment: Sorry, mea culpa. I did however receive working solutions on both threads, so I won't delete either of them. Unless a mod wants to "migrate" the solution from DBA over here, but for now I've added a comment to the other thread. Thanks for pointing out the rule though, won't happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want.

The key idea is to assign a "streak group" to each winning streak, so you can aggregate them.  You can do this by observing:

1. A match in a winning streak is obviously a "win".
2. A winning streak can be identified by counting the number of losses before it -- this is constant for the streak.

Postgres introduced the `filter` clause in 9.4, which makes the syntax a little easier:

```
select player_id, count(*) as streak_length,
       avg(opponent_rank) as avg_opponent_rank
from (select m.*,
             count(*) filter (where result = 'l') over (partition by player_id order by date) as streak_grp
      from matches_m m
     ) m
where result = 'w'
group by player_id, streak_grp;
```

Comment: Among all the solutions I've received, this blew my mind - simply due to the simplicity. For some strange reason it is *slightly* slower than my original query; however, it is so much more readable, and the time loss is negligible (in the 10% range). But most importantly it's exactly what I need, without any further additional joins/subqueries etc., so it's a perfect answer! Thanks!

Comment: @hcac . . . If you have an index on `(hcac, date, result)`, then the performance might significantly improve.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get **all** rows for the highest streaks instead of an aggregated row.

This returns the top 100 streaks with details (would be easier to return all streaks over **n** instead).

```
SELECT ....
FROM
 (
   SELECT streaks.*,
      -- used to filter the top 100 streaks
      -- (would be more efficient without by filtering streaks only in Where)
      Dense_Rank()
      Over (ORDER BY streak DESC, grp, player_id) AS topStreak
   FROM
    (
      SELECT w1.*,
         Count(*) 
         Over (PARTITION BY player_id, grp) AS streak -- count wins per streak
      FROM
       ( --  simplified assigning the group numbers to a single Cumulative Sum
         SELECT m.player_id, m.match_id, m.win, m.DATE, --additional columns needed
            -- cumulative sum over 0/1, doesn't increase for wins, i.e. a streak of wins gets the same number
            Sum(CASE WHEN win = False THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)  
            Over(PARTITION BY m.player_id
                 ORDER BY DATE, match_id
                 ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS grp
         FROM matches_m AS m
         WHERE matches_m.opponent_position<'100' -- should be <100 if it's an INT 
       ) AS w1
      WHERE w1.win = True  -- remove the losses
    ) AS streaks
   -- restrict the number of rows processed by the DENSE_RANK
   -- (could be used instead of DENSE_RANK + WHERE topStreak <= 100)
   WHERE streak > 20 
 ) AS s
WHERE topStreak <= 100
```

Now you can apply any kind of analysis on those streaks. As PG is not my main DBMS I don't know if this is easier using Arrays or Window Functions like `last_value(opponent_player_id) over ...`

Comment: Great solution, and I wish I could award you extra points for making it perfectly readable, including commentary, plus using all my original query variables (so I was able to literally copy/paste this to try it out). I like this solution a lot, and it seems to be the fastest (especially if I limit the streak range) - but it still requires some work to "reduce it" to what I need, and after that the computation time goes up again. But I've bookmarked this for future use, awesome reply!